# PHP Simple HTML DOM search issue

Tags: php, dom

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.wettpoint.com/results/soccer/uefa/uefa-cup-final.html');

$cells = $html->find('table[class=gen] tr');

foreach($cells as $cell) {
  $pre_edit = $cell->plaintext . '<br/>';
  echo $pre_edit;
}

$pos = strpos($pre_edit, "Tennis");

var_dump($pos);

if ($pos == true) {
  echo "string found!";
}
else 
{
  echo "string not found";
}
```

When I search for the string "Tennis" PHP returns "string not found". It only returns "string found" if I search for a string that belongs to the [last iteration of the foreach with length=149](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR8ap.png) (ignoring the first five lines of the $pre_edit var). Could you please give me some advice as to how to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing your search inside the `foreach()` loop, so you'll only **EVER** get the last node retrieved by the loop.

If you'd properly indented the code, you'd see the problem. It should be:

```
foreach($cells as $cell) {
    $pre_edit = $cell->plaintext . '<br/>';
    echo $pre_edit;
    $pos = strpos($pre_edit, "Games");
    var_dump($pos);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        echo "string found!";
    } else {
        echo "string not found";
    }
}
```

Right now you've got:

```
foreach($cells as $cell) {
   blah blah
}
if (strpos(...))) {
     blah blah
}
```

Also note that I've changed `$pos == true` to `$pos !== false`. strpos can and will return a `0` if the string you're searching for is at the beginning the of string. But in PHP, `0 == false` is TRUE, but `0 === false` is FALSE. You need to use the strict equality test, which compares types AND values, to check for the boolean FALSE that strpos returns when the search fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's helpful, how about showing one single message for the first occurrence of the said string, e.g. "found" or "not found" for all of the foreach iterations?

Comment: then don't do output in the loop. if you're just interested if the string is present in ANY nodes, then simply `break();` out of the loop when you find one. or have a counter and do `$x++` whenever you get a match. if $x is non-zero after the loop finishes, you've got that many matches.